# Como extrair e listar valores de um array multidimensional?

Tags: php, array, foreach

Eu tenho este array:

```
Array
(
    [Bairro] => Array
        (
            [0] => Aberta dos Morros
            [1] => CamaquÃ£
            [2] => Cavalhada
            [3] => Cristal
            [4] => GuarujÃ¡
            [5] => HÃ­pica
            [6] => HÃ­pica/Jardins do Prado
            [7] => HÃ­pica/Lagos de Nova Ipanema
            [8] => Ipanema
            [9] => Ipanema/Altos do IpÃª
            [10] => Ipanema/Jardim Verde
            [11] => Menino Deus
            [12] => Nonoai
            [13] => Terraville
            [14] => Tristeza
            [15] => Vila AssunÃ§Ã£o
            [16] => Vila Nova
        )

)
```

Eu consegui obtê-lo através deste script:

```
$cidades = $others['resultado'];

print_r($cidades);
```

Agora eu queria extrair cada valor em forma de string, por exemplo:

**Vila Nova** simplesmente.

Provavelmente declarar um `array` vazio antes, fazer um `foreach` e depois armazenar tudo em uma variável pra obter alguma coisa do tipo:

```
<a href="/Aberta dos Morros">Aberta dos Morros</a>
<a href="/Cavalhada">Cavalhada</a>
<a href="/Menino Deus">Menino Deus</a>
<a href="/Terraville">Terraville</a>
<a href="/Vila Nova">Vila Nova</a>
```

Comment: Não entendi, vc quer so pegar o valor e jogar no link? ou tem algo mais? um foreach não resolve?

Comment: Extrair índices é muito diferente do que realmente quer fazer. Por isso editei a pergunta e o título.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Faz um loop dentro do seu array, algo como:

```
<?php
$cidades = seu array;
for ( $a=0; count($cidades)<$a; $a++ ) {
echo $cidades['Bairro'][$a];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seria algo desse tipo que você quer?

```
      $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cidade");
         while($cidade = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $cidade['id'] ?>"><?php echo $cidade['cidade'] ?></a>
```

Comment: Não é banco de dados. Todos os dados que eu preciso estão dentro de `$cidades` e representa o que está logo acima desta variável.

Comment: A lógica é a mesma, só coloquei a pesquisa do banco de dados e o while, para exemplificar melhor o array.
Onde $cidade['id'] é a posição zero contendo nosso id e $cidade['cidade'] é a posição 1 contendo o nome da nossa cidade.
Coloque seu array em um while junto com seu código que terá o resultado espero, qualquer dúvida não exite em perguntar.

Answer (score 0):

Peguei as infos do BD

```
    $info = ldap_get_entries($connect, $search);
```

Após fiz um foreach para pegar as infos que queria e colocar em outro array:

```
$empresaSemDescricao = array(
        'resultado' => array()
    );
foreach ($info as $inf){
$empresaSemDescricao['resultado'][] = array(
                                'nome'      => $nome,
                                'email'     => $email,
                                'empresa'   => $empresa
                            );
}
```

Depois você consegue ter acesso assim:

```
//Acessar o array que está dentro do array com o sindice 'resultado'
        for($a=0; $a < count($empresaSemDescricao['resultado']); $a++){
            $mensagem .= '    <tr>';
            $mensagem .= '      <td>'.$empresaSemDescricao['resultado'][$a]['nome'].'</td>';
            $mensagem .= '      <td>'.$empresaSemDescricao['resultado'][$a]['email'].'</td>';
            $mensagem .= '      <td>'.$empresaSemDescricao['resultado'][$a]['empresa'].'</td>';
            $mensagem .= '    </tr>';
        }
```